# ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn VS DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having difficulty understanding why using ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn VS DataGridComboBoxColumn with the exact same bindings is giving different results.

The DataGridTemplateColumn results are incorrect.  It seems to be binding to the last record only.

Any idea what's going on ?

[image]

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GUI.SelectedDefinedStream.MassBalanceReferences, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mass Balance Stream">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MassBalanceStreams}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MassBalanceStream}"></ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MassBalanceStreams}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=MassBalanceStream}" Header="Mass Balance Stream"  ></DataGridComboBoxColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Factor">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Factor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Delete}" Style="{StaticResource  MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Click="Delete_MassBalanceReference"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you see any warning in output windows? Guess here is that `SelectedItem` is not finding the write `DataContext`. You can try updating the binding as `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.MassBalanceStream}`.

Comment: @user1672994 no warnings seen.  Not exactly sure how to specify a different context as the data grid column inherits the context from the datagrid ItemsSource.  How would you specify the DataContext?

Comment: You have to use the `RelativeSource` to get the DataContext

Comment: Ok thanks let me look at RelativeSource.  Never used it before